# why active storage record id is null and upload too slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am using latest rails and ruby for a new project, I am using `Active Storage` for upload files ( images and videos ) to `GCP`, when I upload multiples files about 13-18 images, it takes too long to upload and when I check on my database after it finished, my `record_id` is `0` ? is there something wrong?

```
class Gallery < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :files
end
```

my gallery id is UUID for the primary key
is this caused by this? 
because on their documentations said

```
If you are using UUIDs instead of integers as the primary key on your models 
you will need to change the column type of "record_id"
for the active_storage_attachments table in the generated migration accordingly.
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this as well:

It is because the record_id column is of type integer. When you try to enter a uuid into it the following happens and you get the record_id `0` for most attachments:

```rb
2.7.0 :001 > "a2".to_i
 => 0
2.7.0 :002 > "2a".to_i
 => 2
```

In the migration that is created when you set up ActiveStorage there is a line that looks like this:

```rb
t.references :record, null: false, polymorphic: true, index: false
```

For use with UUIDs you'll have to add `type: :uuid` in order to set the type of the foreign key explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

When the model you're attaching to uses uuid as it's primary key, you have to let ActiveStorage know about it.

Two symptoms (that I know of) of *not* doing so, are

- ActiveStorage uploads will be intermittent (due to null id)
- An error like this

```
NoMethodError (undefined method 'attachment_reflections' for nil:NilClass):
```

#### Solution

In a new rails 7 app, simply go into the ActiveStorage migration file and change this line:

```rb
primary_key_type, foreign_key_type = primary_and_foreign_key_types
```

to this:

```rb
primary_key_type, foreign_key_type = [:uuid, :uuid]
```

Then ActiveStorage will work as expected.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72262736/5783745). Note that you may even wish to set the default primary key type to uuid [across your application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72262900/5783745).

---

#### Another (unrelated) reason for slow uploads

Another thing that could cause slow uploads is if you try to pass the ActiveStorage attachements through `.update!` like [this](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#attaching-files-to-records)

```rb
article.update!(
  content: article_params[:content],
  photos: article_params[:photos],
  videos: article_params[:videos]
  )
```

do this instead:

```rb
article.update!(content: article_params[:content])
article.photos.attach(article_params[:photos]) 
article.videos.attach(article_params[:videos])
```

I made this mistake and it took 17 seconds on heroku for 2 uploads totalling 6mb; after the change it took 6 seconds!