# High response time with active storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am using `active_storage` to store and retrieve three plots on a web page on `Heroku`.  The code to retrieve the plot is

```
image_tag plot.variant(resize: '500x500'), class: 'r_plot'
```

Each plot is fairly small, around 500 KByte.  I frequently see the following error from the Logentries heroku add-on:

```
High Response Time: Heroku/Syslog drain
    2020-05-30 21:39:37.733
    671 <158>1 2020-05-30T21:39:35.184905+00:00 heroku router - - at=info method=GET path="/rails/active_storage/representations/long_token/-tmp-plotsPlotname" host=cvd-tracker.herokuapp.com request_id=some_id fwd="ip_address" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5015ms status=302 bytes=1679 protocol=https
```

Why is it taking so long to retrieve these plots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be a few things:

1. The variants are created on demand by the server, so the first time it is called it can take some time and a decent amount of resources to complete.
2. Heroku has an ephemeral filesystem, meaning if you're storing these variants locally then after every new deployment or other event causing a dyno change, the previously created variant will be destroyed so the next time it is called you will have to go through the previous step again.
3. If you aren't storing the variants locally then perhaps your dyno is too small, meaning the server is running out of memory and having to use swap space to complete the variant processing?

Does it sound like any of these apply to your situation?

**EDIT - Background Processing:**

It appears that the actual processing is triggered when [processed](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.1/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/variant.rb#L52) is called so you could do something like this in your rake task:

```
upload = Upload.find(upload_id)
variant = upload.image.variant(options)
was_processed = variant.processed
Rails.logger.info "Processed variant for #{upload.id}" if was_processed
```

I found the above along with some other tips [here](https://tech.kartenmacherei.de/scaling-activestorage-21e962f708d7).

Comment: In regard to your first point, I am creating the images in a background task, but the variants are being produced on demand, so  I will try your suggestion to do them in the background.  In regard to your second point, deployments and dyno changes happen infrequently, but restarts happen twice a day. Do restarts destroy the locally stored variants?

Comment: @Obromios yes restarts will destroy locally stored variants, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku#ephemeral-disk

Answer (score 0):

Extending a little on @Simon L. Brazell's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62115429/5783745), some applications may redirect_to a view that displays the images after they're uploaded, meaning the application may first need to create variants (which takes time).

A few things that may help:

- Consider whether the view needs to display the images at all (e.g. could it display links to the images that the user can click on, thereby producing the variants incrementally (or not at all if you link to the original, full-size images).
- Some variant methods may create variants for a *collection*, consider whether that's necessary (if you're only displaying a subset of the collection, you may not need to create variants for the whole collection).

Another reason

Don't pass attachments through `.update!() like this:

```rb
article.update!(
  content: article_params[:content],
  photos: article_params[:photos],
  videos: article_params[:videos]
  )
```

instead, do [this](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#attaching-files-to-records):

```rb
article.update!(content: article_params[:content])
article.photos.attach(article_params[:photos]) 
article.videos.attach(article_params[:videos])
```

- See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72275348/5783745) for more on that.

Additional notes:

- I saw this in my heroku logs: `Skipping image analysis because the ruby-vips gem isn't installed`, I already had the `ruby-vips` gem installed, but hadn't [installed vips on heroku](https://www.donnfelker.com/how-to-fix-nameerror-uninitialized-constant-vips-on-heroku/) I hoped for a speed improvement after doing so, but I couldn't detect any.

Comment: I do need to display the images but will keep this answer in mind for other contexts.