# Rails Active Storage not working every time. Some time it works, sometime it doesn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am using Active Storage to store images for match score. My class looks like this

```
class TournamentMatch < ApplicationRecords
  has_many_attached :score_cards
end
```

My Score card controller looks like this

```
class Public::ScoreCardsController < Public::BaseController
  def new
    session[:tournament_match_id] = params[:tournament_match_id]
  end

  def create
    tournament_match_id = session[:tournament_match_id]
    tournament_id = session[:tournament_id]
    session[:tournament_match_id] = nil
    session[:tournament_id] = nil

    tournament_match = TournamentMatch.find_by(id: tournament_match_id)

    if tournament_match.score_cards.attach(params['score_cards'])
      flash[:notice] = 'Score card uploaded'
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Score card upload failed'
    end
      
    redirect_to public_results_path(tournament_id: "#{tournament_id}/", anchor: 'results')
  end

  def view
    @tournament_match = TournamentMatch.find_by(id: params[:tournament_match_id])
    render layout: "application"
  end
end
```

So in my create action,I am finding TournamentMatch by id and then attaching score card to it. I am using same image file each time for uploading. But sometimes image is getting attached and sometime it doesn't. `tournament_match.score_cards.attach(params['score_cards']` always returns true in controller. But if i find the same tournament_match and run `tournament_match.score_cards.attach(params['score_cards']` in console then it's returning false. I have also noticed that `record_id` for `active_storage_attachments` is set to 0 when ever image is not saved. But if image is saved then `record_id` have value greater than 0.

I have run out of ideas for debugging. Please suggest me how to debug this problem.

Update: below query is from log file, it shows `record_id` is nil

```
ActiveStorage::Attachment Exists? (0.6ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", nil], ["record_type", "TournamentMatch"], ["name", "score_cards"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My main problem was that I am using `:uuid` for primary key for all my tables so I has to edit ActiveStorage migration to use `:uuid`. I had changed mainly these 2 lines `t.references :record,   null: false, polymorphic: true, index: false, type: :uuid` and `t.references :blob,     null: false, type: :uuid`. My final migration looks like this. And after this ActiveStorage is now woking fine.

```
class CreateActiveStorageTables < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :active_storage_blobs, id: :uuid do |t|
      t.string   :key,        null: false
      t.string   :filename,   null: false
      t.string   :content_type
      t.text     :metadata
      t.bigint   :byte_size,  null: false
      t.string   :checksum,   null: false
      t.datetime :created_at, null: false

      t.index [ :key ], unique: true
    end

    create_table :active_storage_attachments, id: :uuid do |t|
      t.string     :name,     null: false
      t.references :record,   null: false, polymorphic: true, index: false, type: :uuid
      t.references :blob,     null: false, type: :uuid

      t.datetime :created_at, null: false

      t.index [ :record_type, :record_id, :name, :blob_id ], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_uniqueness", unique: true
      t.foreign_key :active_storage_blobs, column: :blob_id
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For new rails 7 apps, inside the ActiveStorage migration file, change this

```rb
primary_key_type, foreign_key_type = primary_and_foreign_key_types
```

to this

```rb
primary_key_type, foreign_key_type = [:uuid, :uuid]
```

It will work now.

#### Notes

- I think this means if you want attachments on any model that has uuid as its primary key, then you'll need to make sure *all* models which you intend to have attachments also use uuid i.e. you can't mix and match (at least, I don't know how).
- See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72262900/5783745) for how to set uuid as the default primary key for all generators across the application.

#### References

The [ActiveStorage docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#setup) says:

> If you are using UUIDs instead of integers as the primary key on your models you will need to change the column type of `active_storage_attachments.record_id` and `active_storage_variant_records.id` in the generated migration accordingly.

More reading [here](https://world.hey.com/ian.bradbury/how-to-configure-rails-active-storage-to-use-uuids-for-database-primary-keys-8ebda248) for older rails versions.