# Set default primary key type across entire rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I will use uuid as the primary key type on *some* tables in a new rails app.

I see the occasional limitation like (at least out of the box) ActiveStorage can only handle attachments on *either* models that have `bigint` or [`uuid` primary key](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#setup)s (not a mix of both).

For this reason, I think it's a cleaner approach to use uuid for every primary key.

Is there a global setting for new rails apps that can be set such that any models generated will automatically use uuid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, set

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.orm :active_record, primary_key_type: :uuid
end
```

in `config/application.rb`.

If you have problems, enable `pgcypto` extension in `postgres`:

```
class EnableUuidExtension < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    enable_extension 'pgcrypto'
  end
end
```

Note: this must be the first migration to run!